# How to obfuscate an 11-char string?

Tags: java, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have an alphanumeric string which its length is 11 that needs to be obfuscated where the obfuscated string should address the following conditions:
- It should remain in an 11 chars length.
- It should be composed from alphanumeric chars only, (i.e. it can be composed from 10 digits + 26 lower case letters + 26 upper case letters).
- There should be a way for deobfuscating into the original string.

Please note that I don't need to obfuscate my whole code, just one string at a time.
- Is there a way in core Java for doing that?
- I would appreciate any help, preferred with an example, a link to an example or to guidelines for such code.
- If someones knows of a third party package that address such case, then please leave a link for it.

Thanks in advance!

---

Regarding the answer/algorithm proposed by Zoul: I implemented everything and currently I have a problem with the concealing issue; this is what I did:

- I currently used the values of the `random_stri` suggested by Zoul. This is just for the test purposes; note that I made it 11-length as I don't need 13.
- As a result of the above I used the ASCII array values you used which is, again, truncated to 11: `[114, 97, 110, 100, 111, 109, 95, 115, 116, 114, 105]`.
- I prepared an array of all 62 available chars and shuffled it which gave me the following shuffled chars array:

```
[h, P, y, 8, o, n, 5, V, X, R, 2, g, Q, p, Z, E, s, x, b, Y, m, v, u, c, j, 9,
 w, 4, I, l, z, B, U, K, S, f, 7, 1, 0, i, k, M, q, e, r, F, 3, C, J, W, O, t,
 d, N, T, A, G, 6, a, D, H, L]
```

This shuffled array is hard-coded and constant from now on for all program executions.

- I loop the 11-chars input string and for each char, I find the obfuscated char's index from the shuffled array as follows: current char + ASCII_ARRAY[current char index]. For example, if my input is '1bS0EMtBbK7', then for the first char which is '1', we perform (1 + 114) which gives us the ASCII value of '1' plus 114, which gives us (49 + 114) --> 163.
- Then, to find the index of the obfuscated char in the shuffled chars array, I perform 163 modulo array length and get the char at this index.

The problem is that the values are still consecutive; i.e. for 2 consecutive inputs, the output results will be consecutive as well! What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You coud use rot13? What's the goal of the obfuscation?

Comment: The goal of the obfuscation is to "hide" the original string which stands for an ID that is generated consecutively; i.e. if the current string is '1bS0EMtBbK5' then the next one will be '1bS0EMtBbK6'; the consecutive generation is out of my control. What is rot13?

Comment: What character set is allowed in the original string?

Comment: As I wrote, the original string  it can be composed from 10 digits + 26 lower case letters + 26 upper case letters - sort of base 62. Thanks !!!

Comment: So basically, you just need to hide the fact that these strings are generated consecutively?

Comment: @RyanThompson Yes, you can sat that. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to keep the result readable, a decent solution is to shift the characters in an array composed of the `a-zA-Z0-9` characters. The shift would be modulo array size, ie. when you get to the end of the array, you wrap to the start again. This is similar to ROT13. And this is how you shift by one:

```
sampletextzZ9
tbnqmfufyuA0a
```

To strengthen the obfuscation a bit, you can use a different shift constant for each letter. Have a second, randomly generated string, and shift each letter of the source text by the ASCII code of the corresponding letter in the randomly generated one:

```
random_string # token
114, 97, 110, 100, 111, 109, 95, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103 # ASCII codes
text # source text to obfuscate

t + 114 = …
e +  97 = …
x + 110 = …
t + 100 = …
```

Then you have to store the random token in the code. Which is security by obscurity, but that’s usually fine in these scenarios. The random token can also be binary, not restricted to printable characters, which would camouflage it a bit inside the resulting object code.

If you need to conceal the consecutive nature of the strings, you can shuffle the `a-zA-Z0-9` array used for shifts. Use a pseudorandom number generator to perform the shuffle and remember the seed, so that you can perform exactly the same shuffle for deobfuscation. With a nice shuffle you could probably drop the random token thing and just shift each character using the same constant.

To deobfuscate you just shift backwards. See also [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) and [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) on Wikipedia.

Comment: This would leave the continuous nature of the Strings pretty obvious

Comment: @zoul I understand the idea but what do you mean by 'Then you have to store the random token in the code'? Do u mean that for every string I obfuscate I'll need to keep the random token somewhere? BTW, do u have by chance a code example?  Another issue: If I'll shuffle the array used for shifts how can I perform the deobfuscation? Thanks !!!

Comment: The random token is kind of a key for the obfuscation scheme, specific for your app. I’ll add another example to make this more clear.

Comment: @zoul so the random key is generated once for all obfuscation actions; i.e. it will be saved as a static string which is initialized one time  for the first time we use the obfuscation method?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You just generate it elsewhere (like use an MD5 of a password or sample `/dev/random`) and store in the source code.

Comment: @AsafLevy: if you want to be able to deobfuscate something that has been obfuscated during a previous execution of your program, the "key" must be hard-coded somewhere and never change.

Comment: @zoul In the example you've given above does the 'random_string' value is the 'ASCII codes'. In addition, I saw that I can shuffle an array using the Collections class - what does it mean to remember the seed? Thanks !

Comment: The token’s value is `"random_string"`, and since you need to convert each character of that to a number to perform the shift, the easiest option is to take the ASCII code of the character. When shuffling the array, you have to be able to perform exactly the same shuffle later when deobfuscating. One way to do it is to remember the seed value for the random number generator used for shuffling. Or you can simply hard-code the whole pre-shuffled character array. You don’t understand the method too much. That’s OK, just go over it with a pencil+paper, read the Wiki articles and think it through.

Comment: @zoul I have a problem with the consecutive issue even after I shuffle the array; please see ahead answer I opened since writing it here was too long... Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you consider your input strings as equivalent to the set of integers from 0 to 62^11-1, then all you really need is a reversible permutation of that set of integers. I would suggest the following: find a number p that is coprime with 62^11. Then find q, the [Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of p, i.e. find q such that p * q = 1 (mod 62^11). Now, to obfuscate, multiply by p (mod 62^11). To deobfuscate, multiply by q (mod 62^11).

Combine this with the per-character randomly-generated rotations suggested by zoul in his answer, and you'll end up with a sequence of strings that look pretty much random to the average observer, but which can easily be transformed back to the ordered input sequence.

I don't know if there is a cryptographically secure method of reversibly permuting a sequence of integers, short of generating and storing a complete random permutation, which is probably not feasible for a list of size 62^11.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't understand it... both algorithm and the English are too complicated for me :) again, thanks for your effort !!!